# IOS- How to change text color and selected date border color in UIdatepicker?

Tags: uidatepicker, custom-datetimepicker

As default ios uidatepicker don't allow to change any text color or highlighted date color.
Is there only way to create custom date picker? Help me out. 
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you may consider to look at the following links for custom date picker using NSCalendar class
https://github.com/mwermuth/MWDatePicker
http://blog.deeplink.me/post/81386967477/how-to-easily-customize-uidatepicker-for-ios

Comment: thanks for reply. Earlier i have gone through all those 2 links. MWDatePicker didn't even show any proper output to me. Have u tried those links? If yes then help me with guideline to use them . Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I have gone through these links.for MWDatePicker first date were invisible but changing the font color like this [datePicker setFontColor:[UIColor blueColor]]; in viewdidLoad in MWViewController.m make them visible.